# I cant use material button using com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components, material-components-android

Hi i want use material buttons like buttons in links below: 
https://material.io/components/buttons/#text-button

but when i added:

```
compile group: 'com.google.android.material', name: 'material', version: '1.1.0-alpha01'
```

and used :

my codes are in below

i had already used many com.google.android.material implementations but cant do so some of my tries:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
```

app gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.esppad.fansy4"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material
    compile group: 'com.google.android.material', name: 'material', version: '1.1.0-alpha01'

    //implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
}
```

and my main activity code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
 android:gravity="center">
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
     android:text="material"
     app:strokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
     app:strokeWidth="2dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

     />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button"
         style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Button" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button2"

     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

my build gradle is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this   `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`
OR
 try to migrate your app to androidx [here is the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSFij.png)

Comment: In which way the migration to androidx is an alternative to use the material components library?

Answer (score 4):

To add [material text buttons](https://material.io/components/buttons/#text-button) to your app follow these steps:

- **Add the [dependency](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#1-depend-on-our-library)** in `build.gradle`:

```groovy
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
```

- **Change your app theme** to inherit from a [Material Components theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme) (`Theme.MaterialComponents.*`).
- And just **use the [`MaterialButton`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md)** in your layout with the style [**`Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md#text-button):

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/material_text_button"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="..."/>
```

[image]

Comment: And what is the issue?

Comment: it doesnt recognize and dont load any style ... when i run the application i dont get error but i get runtime error

Comment: Did you use a [Material Theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme) for your app?

Comment: @pouyairanpour check the updated answer and the comment. Both have the link to the setup of the material component library and the theme.

Answer (score 3):

The Material Design documentation clearly states how you should incorporate the library into your application. You can read it at https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/.

In short, you have to depend on the library with:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'
```

where `<version>`is the latest version (currently 1.1.0-alpha09).

After this, you need to update your app theme to use material design. Go to `src/main/res/values/styles.xml` and update the app theme there:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="<theme>">
   <!-- ... -->
</style>
```

where `<theme>` can be one of the following:

```
Theme.MaterialComponents
Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar
Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar
```

Finally, you're ready to use any material element you want. For your button:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
  android:text="material"
  app:strokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
  app:strokeWidth="2dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
```

Comment: how shoud i use style ? in app theme ? can u tell me more ?

Comment: @pouyairanpour I edited the answer with more information regarding themes :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line

```
  compile group: 'com.google.android.material', name: 'material', version: '1.1.0-alpha01'
```

Use this

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
```

Don't forget **Change your app theme to inherit from a Material Components theme**